# Windows 10 BSOD Kernel-Power

Tags: laptop, windows-10, bsod

As the title states, I'm getting random BSODs in Windows 10. The Windows event viewer is just showing me Kernel-Power. This issue has persisted in multiple complete reinstalls of Windows 8, 8.1 and 10. It is highly random, sometimes it doesn't happen for 2-3 days, other times it happens within seconds of every restart as soon as Windows boots up. I'm mentioning my configuration below: (please keep in mind that it's a laptop and not a desktop)

HP Envy 14, Core i5 4200U, 4GB RAM, Intel HD Graphics 4400/Nvidia GT740M, 750GB HDD + 24GB SSD

So far I've ruled out RAM and HDD. RAM through memtest and HDD because I tried installing Windows on both the SSD and HDD, and the issue persisted nonetheless. I've Googled a ton and now I'm drawing a blank. I'm including one of the memory dumps as well as a screenshot from Bluescreenview and a .txt file from Windows event viewer here:

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/2a17gxybuabf6/BSOD

I need help in narrowing down the component which might be causing this issue. I know PSU is a huge factor in Kernel-Power issue but since this is a laptop, I don't know how to test this one.

Comment: The "Kernel-Power" errors are simply telling you your machine turned off without Windows being shutdown (properly).  "I've ruled out RAM ... through memtest"  How long did you let it run for? How many passes completed total? Continuous or interrupted?  Memtest should be run for days, and is not fool proof.  From my experience what your describing does sound like RAM problems -- I'd say start by trying a different, known-good stick of RAM.

Comment: I let it run for 6 hours non-stop before I interrupted it, I think it was about 12 passes but in any case there were no errors. I'm also getting no errors in Ubuntu, It runs smoothly without as much as a hiccup. Wouldn't RAM problems persist in Linux? On the other hand, the laptop is only crashing constantly in Windows. Unfortunately I don't have another RAM stick at hand to test with.